# Using Firebase only for the authentication in a Postgres stack

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using a React Native (Expo), GraphQL, Node, and Postgres stack and I have a simple email and password authentication setup with JWT.  I want to separate the concept of user identity and user account by allowing multiple identities to link to a single user account. In other words, I want to implement Google, Facebook, Twitter OAuth for a user to log into the same account.

Does it make sense to use Firebase just for the authentication? This means I will essentially have two user databases, one for the authentication in Firebase and another in Postgres for any other operations like posting, purchase, reviews, etc.

Comment: It makes sense if it meets the needs of your app.  That's something only you can determine.  If you benefit from the duplication of data, and are willing to manage whatever downsides there might be to it, what's stopping you from moving forward?

Comment: BTW this question is a bit too opinionated to fit will on Stack Overflow.  I suggest posting to a discussion forum such as Reddit in order to start an open-ended conversation. https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/

Comment: Would you say this a common setup tho? I'm pretty new to app development so not sure of the convention

Comment: Yes, putting Firebase Hosting in front of other content to be cached in its CDN via Cloud Functions and Cloud Run is one of the main use cases.

Comment: @Kevvv What did you end up doing here? I've come across this post while looking for something similar so while it may be closed, it's still potentially useful to others. I have the exact same setup as you Expo, GraphQL, and PostgreSQL and also wondered about using Firebase _just_ for auth. Right now, I'm using simple email/password with JWT. Thanks!

Comment: I believe I created two identical databases for Postgres and Firebase in case GraphQL needed to query through the user's info or if I needed to part ways with Firebase. My flow for the authentication was to go through Firebase first and then to Postgres. Also, Firebase has a way to combine different OAuth accounts into one if you have the same email, so I used the email as the unique identifier for GraphQL, if I rememer correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scenario you're sketching means you're using Firebase for authentication, and then implement your own authorization system on top of that. This is completely feasible, and even quite common.

What you'll need to do on your side is [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), so that you can be certain the user is who they claim to be. Then you can use the information from that token to look up additional information in your own database *and* authorize access to the data in that system.

The verification of the token and authorization will need to happen in the backend/trusted system of course, as client-side they could be easily spoofed by users. So similar to Firebase's server-side security rules and Cloud Functions, you'll need your own trusted environment where you check the authorization and then expose the data.